# Deploying egg on Scrapinghub

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapinghub

I Deployed a project on the scraping-hub but my spider isn't working because scraping-hub uses an old version of twisted library. The project is working fine on my local machine, Is there anyway that i could make an egg of the twisted updated version and deploy it on scraping-hub.

Comment: You may want to contact help@scrapinghub.com so they can help you with this

Comment: yeah Posted this issue on @support/scrpinghub

Answer (score -1):

Would this help: http://doc.scrapinghub.com/shub.html#deploying-dependencies
?

It shows how to deploy specific dependencies for you project to scrapinghub cloud service.